# Qt C++ QRegExp parse string

Tags: c++, regex, qt

I have the string `str`. I want to get two strings ('+' and '-'):

```
QString str = "+asdf+zxcv-tyupo+qwerty-yyuu oo+llad dd ff";

// I need this two strings:
// 1. For '+': asdf,zxcv,qwerty,llad dd ff
// 2. For '-': tyupo,yyuu oo


QRegExp rx("[\\+\\-](\\w+)");
int pos = 0;

while ((pos = rx.indexIn(str, pos)) != -1) {
    qDebug() << rx.cap(0);
    pos += rx.matchedLength();
}
```

Output I need:

```
"+asdf" 
"+zxcv" 
"-tyupo" 
"+qwerty" 
"-yyuu oo" 
"+llad dd ff"
```

Output I get:

```
"+asdf" 
"+zxcv" 
"-tyupo" 
"+qwerty" 
"-yyuu" 
"+llad"
```

If I replace `\\w` by `.*` the output is:

```
"+asdf+zxcv-tyupo+qwerty-yyuu oo+llad dd ff"
```

Comment: `QRegExp rx("[+-]");` would be enough..

Comment: Yes I need check + or - and get option.

Comment: Sorry, I change the text. See OUTPU (I NEED)

Comment: I think it will be something like `QRegExp rx("[\\+\\-][a-z ]+");`

Comment: yes, work for this exapmle Thanks!.

Comment: If you can, use `QRegularExpression` instead `QRegExp`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
[+-]([^-+]+)
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qZ4fZ1/1)

The regex breakdown:

- `[+-]` - either a `+` or `-`
- `([^-+]+)` - a capturing group matching 1 or more symbols other than `-` and `+`.

Answer (score 2):

<s>Your regexp is excessive:</s>

```
[\\+\\-](\\w+)
\______/\____/
    ^     ^--- any amount of alphabetical characters
    ^--- '+' or '-' sign
```

So what you are capturing is the `+`/`-` sign, *and* any word that follows it directly. If you want to capture only the `+`/`-` signs, use `[+-]` as a regular expression.

**EDIT:**

To get the strings including the spaces, you need

```
QRegExp rx("[+-](\\w|\\s)+");
```

Comment: QRegExp rx("[+-](\\w+)");  Output: "+asdf" 
"+zxcv" 
"-tyupo" 
"+qwerty" 
"-yyuu" 
"+llad"   .    I need with spaces, for example "+yyuu oo"

Comment: @Šerg, `QRegExp rx("[+-]")` if you want just `+` and `-`. If you need to capture something else, please edit your question to include the desired output.

Comment: This regex is very inefficient. Using alternation with a quantifier involves redundant backtracking.